# Python: Update value in dictionary while looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to loop through a list and would like that with each loop the value in the dictionary update according to the value in the loop. Something like

The value I want to update is "categoryId":"2030110" which is in body.

```
Categoryid = [2040831,2029816,2029818,2029814,2084696]

body = {"operationName":"GetCategoryForFilterPage","variables":{"categoryId":"2030110","facets":[],"page":1,"pageSize":1000,"searchPhrase":"","sortBy":"RELEVANCE"},"query":"query GetCategoryForFilterPage($categoryId: String!, $searchPhrase: String, $sortBy: SortBy!, $page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!, $facets: [FacetParameterInput!]) {\n  category(categoryId: $categoryId) {\n    id\n    seoTitle\n    name\n    namePath\n    pathSlug\n    seoText\n    navigation {\n      id\n      path {\n        ...NavigationItem\n        __typename\n      }\n      siblings {\n        ...NavigationItem\n        __typename\n      }\n      childrenSortedByHits {\n        ...ChildNavigationItem\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    productSearch(searchPhrase: $searchPhrase, sortBy: $sortBy, page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize, facets: $facets) {\n      facets {\n        name\n        type\n        displayName\n        facetOpened\n        nameInUrl\n        isTranslated\n        unitText\n        values {\n          displayName\n          name\n          hits\n          min\n          max\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      productHits\n      productReferences {\n        ...ProductReference\n        __typename\n      }\n      ads {\n        ...Ads\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment NavigationItem on CategoryNavigationItem {\n  categoryId\n  hits\n  selected\n  category {\n    name\n    pathSlug\n    categoryImageFileName\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ChildNavigationItem on ProductCategoryChildNavigationItem {\n  categoryId\n  hits\n  selected\n  category {\n    name\n    pathSlug\n    categoryImageFileName\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductReference on ProductReference {\n  id\n  ticket\n  searchResultProduct {\n    ...ProductForList\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment Ads on AdContainer {\n  banner {\n    imageUrl\n    url\n    text\n    displayMode\n    buttonText\n    __typename\n  }\n  productReferences {\n    ...ProductReference\n    __typename\n  }\n  ticket\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductForList on SearchResultProduct {\n  id\n  displayName\n  primaryImageId\n  manufacturerName\n  manufacturerProductIdentifier\n  displaySpecifications\n  oneLiner\n  internalProduct\n  nameSlug\n  hasPrimaryServiceProduct\n  primaryServiceProductErpIdentifier\n  energyClass\n  energyLabelImageId\n  reviewScore\n  isNewProduct\n  promotedSpecifications(take: 4) {\n    name\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  price {\n    campaignPercentage\n    campaignType\n    formatted {\n      price\n      originalPrice\n      __typename\n    }\n    isBestSeller\n    isBid\n    isCampaign\n    isRecommendedProduct\n    price\n    priceExcludingVat\n    originalPrice\n    serviceDurationMonths\n    __typename\n  }\n  categoryName\n  availability {\n    externalStock {\n      leadTime\n      quantity\n      __typename\n    }\n    availabilityDetails {\n      formattedDateUtc\n      key\n      __typename\n    }\n    availabilityStatus\n    internalStock {\n      quantity\n      showAlwaysInStock\n      __typename\n    }\n    isAvailableForSale\n    isPreOrder\n    productLifeCycleState\n    showAvailabilityQuantities\n    showEtaDate\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"}

for var in Categoryid:
    print(body.update({"categoryId":var}))
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear.

Comment: @SARANSURYA When I try to update using above loop the body value does not update.

Comment: use `body['variables']['categoryId'] = xxxx` to set the value and then print the body.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Vishal Singh works:

```
body['variables']['categoryId'] = xxxx
```